# How can implode the values from a foreach?

Tags: php

I have a html table with some accounts information, and I inserted a checkbox to check the accounts, and check all the emails from the checked users.

To get this information I created this function

```
function get_multiple($sendcheck) {
    $get_emails = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE user_id IN ("; 

    foreach($sendcheck as $key) {
        $teste =  implode(',', $sendcheck);
    }

    $get_emails .=  $teste;
    $get_emails .= ")"; 

    $array = db_array($get_emails, 'a+');

    send_multiple($array);
}
```

I'm calling the checkboxes posts here

```
if (isset($_POST['sendmultiple']) && !empty($_POST['sendcheck'])) {
    $sendcheck = $_POST['sendcheck'];
    get_multiple($sendcheck);
} else {
   $sendcheck = NULL;
}
```

After that, I printed the checked emails

```
function send_multiple($array) {
  foreach($array as $key ) {
    echo  implode(',', $key);
  }
}
```

This function is printing all the selected account emails, but without the semicolon, what's happening?

Comment: You don't need `foreach` around `implode`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `foreach`.

```
function get_multiple($sendcheck){

    $get_emails = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE user_id IN ("; 
    $teste =  implode(',', $sendcheck);
    $get_emails .=  $teste;
    $get_emails .= ")"; 
    $array = db_array($get_emails, 'a+');
    send_multiple($array);

}
```

And to print them with semicolons between:

```
function send_multiple($array) {
    echo implode(';', $array);
}
```

You use `implode` *instead of* writing a loop that appends each element to the string.

Comment: thanks, now i'm not using foreach anymore, but how can i put semi collon on the printed emails?

Comment: I've added printing with semicolons to my answer. Again, don't use `foreach`, just use `implode`. And semicolon is `;`, not `,`.